# React Router app in IIS inside subdirectory Not Working using URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, react-redux, url-rewriting, react-router

I have a react router in my react app that I am trying to host in IIS. I have URL Rewrite installed. with the following web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I use localhost:port as the react project's main directory. It works.
However, I need to use a relative path/ a sub-directory. Since we have other applications hosted in the same port.
So I need to host it inside of localhost:80/firstdirectory. This is where index.html will go.

Redirects and Routing are simply not working. If I try to use React Router's redirect to a relative path of '/seconddirectory', it will redirect me to localhost/seconddirectory, instead of localhost:80/firstdirectory/seconddirectory.

Since I use CRA. I have tried this with hostname: '.' and without. It really doesnt want to work.

Answer (score 1):

So far I may have found solutions to my problem. I still need to keep testing to make sure nothing else is affected.

This is the web config that I ended up using, along with URL Rewrite

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite Text Requests" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/subdirectoryhere/api(.*)$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/subdirectoryhere/index.html" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also have

```
homepage: '.'
```

in my create-react-app application, which i'll have to move to my own boilerplate later.

I also had to change my i18n.tsx backend loadPath to a relative path

```
backend: {
            loadPath: './locales/{{lng}}.json'
        }
```

Lastly my Router is fed the basename

```
const getBasename = (path: any) => path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

```
<Router basename={getBasename(window.location.pathname)}>
...
</Router
```