404 error when accessing react route in iis application
I'm having trouble accessing the routes of my application that is hosted on an IIS server. The route is opening and navigating through the screens. The redirection works, but if I just enter the route, or manually rewrite to a different endpoint, it returns the IIS 404 screen.
my environment is configured for a standard, in which a homologation system is differentiated by a route, for example:
homologacao_teste/application1
homologacao_teste/application2
in my real case, I am hosting on my 192.168...../vcn_web/ as a base route.
web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/vcn_web/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/javascript" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Router in app.js:
<Router basename="/vcn_web">

Homepage in package.json:
"homepage": "/vcn_web/",

Apparently everything is configured correctly, but I still get a 404 return, what should I adjust?

It looks like you want to use a subdirectory under your project as your site entry, you can refer to this same case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274949/react-router-app-in-iis-inside-subdirectory-not-working-using-url-rewrite
